iTextSharp Header is merging with document content
I need is header table on all pages and page content/table which will be different every page. I am using PdfPageEventHelper for header. I have below code in OnOpenDocument
 header.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left+20, writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin + 10), writer.DirectContent); 

In Main I have
 Rectangle r = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
 Document doc = new Document(r);

 doc.SetMargins(15f, 15f, 35f, 35f);
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Create));
 writer.PageEvent = new PDFHeaderAndFooter(this._configuration, companyViewModel, doctorDetails);
 doc.Open();

and after this my page table is adding as below
 document.add(table). 

But this is overlapping with my header table. What could be the reason?

Is your header table only 10 units high? You start it 10 units above the margin, so if your table is larger, it will overlap regular content.

Can you please elaborate what is mean by 10 units above the margin? My header table has 5 rows. and I want line separator (which should be part of header) between header & body content.

I expect my header table should start from 10 units above top from page and should end after line spectator.  My document  table should start from below that. How can I set my margins for this?  It seems that doc.SetMargins(15f, 15f, 35f, 35f); is applicable for header as well.
